# How to load i2c-dev module on boot with systemd

Tags: linux, display, arch-linux, external-display, kernel-module

I'd like to control my monitor brightness with `ddcutil`, which [requires the `i2c-dev` module to be loaded](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#External_monitors).

It is not loaded automatically, so I'm following [the directions on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module#Automatic_module_loading_with_systemd) to try to automatically load it with systemd. `systemd-modules-load.service` has no errors, yet the module isn't loaded on boot.

```
# Not loaded
[rcorre@midova ~]$ sudo ddcutil setvcp 10 10
Display not found

# But I've got a file in modules-load.d
[rcorre@midova ~]$ cat /etc/modules-load.d/i2c-dev
i2c-dev

# The logs have always been rotated on boot ...
[rcorre@midova ~]$ sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2019-09-05 06:51:35 EDT; 14min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
 Main PID: 449 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-modules-load.service

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.

# ... so I try restarting the service
[rcorre@midova ~]$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-modules-load
[rcorre@midova ~]$ sudo systemctl status systemd-modules-load
● systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2019-09-05 07:10:19 EDT; 14s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 8189 ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8189 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 05 07:10:19 midova systemd[1]: Stopping Load Kernel Modules...
Sep 05 07:10:19 midova systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
Sep 05 07:10:19 midova systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.

# Still no luck
[rcorre@midova ~]$ sudo ddcutil setvcp 10 10
Display not found

# But I can load it manually
[rcorre@midova ~]$ sudo modprobe i2c-dev
[rcorre@midova ~]$ sudo ddcutil setvcp 10 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each configuration file is named in the style of `/etc/modules-load.d/<program>.conf`.

The `.conf` suffix is **required** for modules-load.d – other files are ignored. (This is how the program distinguishes between actual configuration and leftover backups, e.g. various distros' .pacnew/.rpmnew files.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to run `modprobe` during boot. If you have LXDE as your desktop, you can put `modprobe i2c-dev` in `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` as a new line containing `@sudo modprobe i2c-dev`. I haven't tried other methods of this for boot but you might be able to add it to `.xinitrc` that will execute when X starts the desktop. You can also put it in `.bashrc` but that will require a terminal window be opened to execute it. Also in Arch Linux menu `Preferences`, you can configure the `Default applications for LXSession` then click on the Autostart button to add a manually started app (which is same as editing the `../LXDE/autostart` file).